# How to use TPUv4s on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Following documentation from [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/kubernetes-engine-setup) I'm able to have GKE manage the lifecycle of TPUv3s for my tasks. However I can't use TPUv4s using the same methodology. Is it even possible given that TPUv4s can only be instantiated as TPU VMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TPU v4 is not yet supported on GKE.  We should have a preview later this year though.